# 1000 upvotes yet no gold tag badge?

Tags: support, badges, upvotes, tag-badges

Using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), I've been tracking the *"How many upvotes do I have for each tag?"* query. I've at last hit 1000, yet I don't seem to have received a gold badge for this.

[image]

Have I misunderstood how to earn this badge?

Comment: How many answers....you need at least 200?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your *current* score is 969:

[image]

Your score is comprised of all upvotes on non-wiki answers minus downvotes on the same. It sounds as if that query *only counts upvotes*, which would not be the same thing as the *score* for your posts.

If you answered more questions or got upvotes, you'll have to wait until the score updates (once a day, at around 03:00am UTC).

Comment: Thanks Martjn, I hadn't even ever visited that tab. Get so used to screens you start missing them.

Answer (score 2):

*Downvotes* on your answers will also count towards the score (negatively), and its the *score* which determines if you qualify for the tag badge or not. That query apparently only counts upvotes, and **does not deserve the subtitle**

> how long before I get tag badges?

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/591042/how-many-downvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag?UserId=21061) shows you have 31 downvotes on [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) answers, so your total score is 1000 - 31 = 969, which equals the score on your profile.

For tracking your progress towards tag badges, [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/577560/what-is-my-total-tag-score-for-each-tag) is a better one.

Answer (score 1):

You:

> Gave 341 non-wiki answers with a total score of 969. <sub>([source](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21061/ian?tab=tags))</sub>

You've got just a few more points to go. Keep in mind that downvotes *do* count against this score.